# set setContentView depending on conditions

Tags: java, android

I have a `Main.java` file that extends `Activity`. It is called by `AndroidManifest.xml` as the default `activity`. I have a `SharedPreferences` variable that I am calling and depending on if it is set or not determines if I load `Main.java` or `Somethingelse.java`. How do I switch from loading `Main.java` to `Somethingelse.java` programmatically?

Comment: Can you explain a little better exactly *what* you want such as your conditions and show what you have so far? This will allow us to give you the best way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Are you trying to change the default activity that's launched, or the setContentView? I'm confused.

Comment: You have 2 alternatives: 1) Create 2 activities, then launch one of them from `Main` depending on `SharedPreferences`, or 2) Set content view based on `SharedPreferences` in `Main`.

Comment: Most likely, you want to change `Activities` because I assume there will be different logic for each. Just start the first then launch the other or stay in `Main` depending on the `SharedPref`

Comment: I was building the `View` for each activity in the `onCreate` method, after reading @AndrewT.post I will place each of the `Views`in there own `Class` returning the content needed for `setContentView` and depending on the `SharedPreference` will determine what `Class` to call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't switch the Default Activity that's loading programatically, but you can use an if statement to switch the setContentView if that's what you mean:

```
if (statement) {
     setContentView(R.layout.example);
} else {
     setContentView(R.layout.example2);
}
```

If what you mean is that you want to launch a certain activity at launch from a SharedPreferences variable, do what [Andrew T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2821954/andrew-t) suggested, and launch the MainActivity, then launch either one of the activities based on the stored variable.

Comment: That is pretty much what I am going to be doing.